# How to draw plot.dendrogram with labels at different levels (like plot.hclust)?

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust

when I use default `plot()` for `hclust` object, it places leaves' labels at different distances, just as I need:

```
data(mtcars)
plot(hclust(dist(mtcars)))
```

[image: plot.hclust]

But when I do the same for `dendrogram` object, it aligns all labels to the same level:

```
plot(as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mtcars))))
```

[image: plot.dendrogram]

How to disable this alignment and make it behave exactly like for `hclust`? 
I tried `hang=0` but it makes all "leaves" to have zero length:

[image: plot.dendrogram with hang=0]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adjusting the `hang` parameter.

```
plot(as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mtcars)), hang = 0))
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! the problem with `hang=0` is that it also sets the length of all "leaves" to zero (I'll add the picture to the question). Do you know how to solve that issue?

Comment: I see the problem. Have you tried to set `hang=0.1` or any other small number?

Comment: yes I tried: unfortunately setting `hang` to anything above 0 makes all labels aligned

Comment: oh actually not exactly: with really small number like `hang=0.01` I do have non-aligned labels, but then again the length of the "leaves" is close to 0

Comment: `plot(hclust(dist(mtcars)))` seems to just add branch of fixed length to the leave. Therefore, the leaves at the end go below 0 (which doesn't make sense). The version with `as.dendrogram` ends at 0. Thus, you might need to live with short leaves at the end. It may be worth looking into the `ggtree` package for more flexibility in plotting trees.

Comment: Seems you're right. I wanted to avoid additional packages but apparently I'll have to. Will try `ggtree`.

Answer (score -1):

```
plot(hclust(dist(mtcars)), hang = -1)
```

From the [help](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/hclust) page:

> hang
> The fraction of the plot height by which labels should hang below the rest of the plot. A negative value will cause the labels to hang down from 0.

Comment: well your answer takes `hclust` object while I need it to work with the `dendrogram` object. And the output is exactly what I *don't* need: all labels are aligned to the same level, while I need to keep different distances.